# How to checked specific position checbox in spinner android

Tags: android, adapter, android-spinner, android-checkbox

I want a `spinner` with checkbox (custom `adapter` xml will have one image,textview and checkbox in horizontal line)and whatever checkbox I check it should be checked even when I reopen application. That specific checkbox state should be save and when I open application again that specific checkbox should be checked in spinner that's it.

Description:

I am making a text to speech application and when I click on spinner country name,flag and one checkbox is in one horizontal line and there are almost 50 countries using custom adapter but what I need is whenever user click any country language to translate language application should save that checkbox or that particular position if the user comes again to click on the spinner the user should know which language was selected before by showing checkbox checked that's all.
Thanks looking forward to your answers

This is what I have and want to mark one checkbox checked

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

//This is how to add in adapter from activity/fragment

```
    CountryAdapter adapter = new CountryAdapter(getApplicationContext(), new CountryAdapter.CountryChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCountryChange(CountryModel countryModel) {
            //persist selected country name in preference
        }
    });

    List<CountryModel> list = loadAllCountries();
    adapter.add(list);
    String selectedCountry = getSelectedCountry();
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(selectedCountry)){
        adapter.setCountrySelected(selectedCountry);
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

CountryModel  is model class for your adapter.

```
public class CountryModel {

private String name;

private Drawable countryFlagIcon; //it could be bitmap or resource Id of the icon

/*
    isSelected would be true when user selects that particular Country
*/

private boolean isSelected;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Drawable getCountryFlagIcon() {
    return countryFlagIcon;
}

public void setCountryFlagIcon(Drawable countryFlagIcon) {
    this.countryFlagIcon = countryFlagIcon;
}

public boolean isSelected() {
    return isSelected;
}

public CountryModel(String _name,Drawable _countryFlagIcon){
    name = _name;
    countryFlagIcon = _countryFlagIcon;
}

public CountryModel(String _name,Drawable _countryFlagIcon,boolean _isSelected){
    this(_name,_countryFlagIcon);
    isSelected = _isSelected;
}

public void setSelected(boolean _isSelected){
    isSelected = _isSelected;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = 1;

    result = 31 * result + (name == null ? 0 : name.hashCode());

    result = 31 * result + Boolean.valueOf(isSelected).hashCode();

    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(obj == null || obj.getClass() != getClass()) return false;

    if(this == obj) return true;

    CountryModel model = (CountryModel)obj;

    return name != null && name.equals(model.name) && isSelected == model.isSelected;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return "[country = " + name + " isSelected = " + isSelected + "]";
}
```

}

CountryAdapter adapter class for Spinner

```
public class CountryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private static final int VIEW_TYPES = 2;

private static final int TYPE_SELECTED = 0;

private static final int TYPE_UNSELECTED = 1;

private List<CountryModel> countryModelList;

private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

private CountryChangeListener countryChangeListener;

public CountryAdapter(Context context,CountryChangeListener _countryChangeListener){
    countryModelList = new ArrayList<>();
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    countryChangeListener = _countryChangeListener;
}

public void add(List<CountryModel> list){
    countryModelList.addAll(list);
}

public synchronized void setCountrySelected(int position) {
    updateCountryListDta(position);
    if(countryChangeListener != null){
        countryChangeListener.onCountryChange(getItem(position));
    }
}

public synchronized void setCountrySelected(String selectedCountry) {
    for(CountryModel model:countryModelList){
        if(model.getName().equals(selectedCountry)){
            model.setSelected(true);
        }else{
            model.setSelected(true);
        }
    }
}

private void updateCountryListDta(int position) {
    for(CountryModel model:countryModelList){
        model.setSelected(false);
    }
    getItem(position).setSelected(true);
}



@Override
public int getCount() {
    return countryModelList.size();
}

@Override
public CountryModel getItem(int position) {
    return countryModelList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return VIEW_TYPES;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    CountryModel model = getItem(position);
    return model.isSelected() ? TYPE_SELECTED : TYPE_UNSELECTED;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    if(view == null ){
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.country_dropdown_item,parent,false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
    }else{
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        viewHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);//remove previous Attached listener
    }

    CountryModel model = getItem(position);

    int type = getItemViewType(position);

    viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(type == TYPE_SELECTED ? true:false);

    viewHolder.name.setText(model.getName());

    viewHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            setCountrySelected(position);
        }
    });
    return view;
}



private class ViewHolder{
    private TextView name;

    private CheckBox checkBox;

    ViewHolder(View view){
        name = view.findViewById(R.id.countryName);//replace with your resource ids
        checkBox = view.findViewById(R.id.countryCheckBox);//replace with your resource ids
    }
}

interface CountryChangeListener{
    void onCountryChange(CountryModel countryModel);
}
```

}

Comment: where are you adding position in any database?

Comment: public void onCountryChange(CountryModel countryModel) {
 //persist selected country name in preference
}
in onCountryChange you can persist in sharedPreference , file or in database.
when you want to set it to adapter
String selectedCountry = getSelectedCountry();
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(selectedCountry)){
 adapter.setCountrySelected(selectedCountry);
}

Answer (score 0):

You can save the state of your Checkbox in the onsavedinstancestate and retrieve this state in your oncreate method. This is only for shortterm usage, if you want to save the state of your Checkbox for future use of the application you should use a database for the states of each Checkbox or sharedpreferences. For shortterm you can use something like this
     override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        val checkBox : CheckBox
        outState.putBoolean("checkbox_x_checked",checkBox.isChecked)
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)

```
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState)
    val checkBox : CheckBox
    //assign all Views and Ids 
    if (savedInstanceState!= null){
        checkBox.isChecked = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("checkbox_x_checked",false)
    }
}
```

If you want to save the data for Long term use, you can write the data onchecked into sharedpreferences for example something like this

```
    // get shared preferences
    val sharedpref  = getSharedPreferences("checked_checkboxes", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val sharedpref_editor = sharedpref.edit()
    //assign checkboxes
    val checkBox_x : CheckBox

    //set checkbox old value
    checkbox_x.isChecked = sharedpref.getBoolean("checkbox_x_checked",false)

    //assign oncheckedchangelistener for the checkboxes
    checkBox_x.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
        sharedpref_editor.putBoolean("checkbox_x_checked",isChecked)
        sharedpref_editor.apply()
    }
```

Comment: But the problem is all the checkbox will be checked which i do not want i want to check specific position checkbox fox example i checked 5th item in spinner so when i reopen application 5th item checkbox inside the spinner should already be checked

Comment: let me know the condition which i should put inside spinner to check the same checkbox

Comment: Not all checkboxes will be marked as checked, it checks of the checkbox should be marked as checked and if there is no data for the checkbox it won't be marked as checked. When you check a checkbox it will write data to shared preferences which will be retrived on reopen, which says mark this checkbox as checked

Comment: where are we storing position of specific checkobx?  we are storing true or false and when we will get data from sharedprefrence and if sharedprefrence has true in it then it will mark all checkbox checked because there is no position as i said if we check 5th position or 89th position where is it differentiating about position? Thanks for your response

Comment: It is inside spinner and there will be only one checkbox.setoncheckchangelistner because we are using custom adapter

Comment: in custom adapter one view we create again and again but the data is difference in the same way checkbox will be one and data would be different in each row so where are we storing position if i check particular checkbox from list inside spinner

Comment: You Need to record something, which is specific for a line and is the same everytime you open the app. You save for this data if the checkbox for the according line is already checked

Comment: Please see my output image link i have edited my question